# Is this... ? How to give a negative answer

Tags: questions

Which one is the correct answer to the following question: *"Is this your house?"* ?

1. No, it isn't.
2. No, this isn't.

The first sounds better to me.

Comment: Why do you think only one can be "correct"?

Comment: For some reason, "No, it's snot" seems to be a common reply in many such cases.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like *"It isn't"* would be better if you're there in the house. Or where there are no other alternative options as to what the subject is. *"The house isn't mine, but it belongs to my friend."*

*"This isn't"* implies *"Not this one, but that one over there is."* As if you're in a car giving directions responding to a question of *"Which house?"*

I'm not a hotshot with grammar, but I remember something like this from a foreign language and I feel it applies.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with grammar. Both alternatives are entirely grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct with different implications.

> No, it isn't.

Simple statement. It is not my house.

> No, this isn't.

Simple statement with a qualitative implication. 
**This** is not my house. (**That** one is.) [or] (**This** is my **friend's** house.) [or something similar]

Answer (score -3):

They both make sense but the first one is better. :)

Comment: **Why** is it better?